# Modify json-value using Rapture

Tags: json, scala

Circe has this funciontality to modify a json value based on its path:

`root.order.items.each.quantity.int.modify(_ * 2)`

Say I have a list of rapture paths like so:

`val paths: List[Vector[Either[Int, String]]] = ...`

What's the best way of modifying a rapture-json based on a vector-path?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
val newItems = 
  root.order.items.map { item => 
    item.copy(_.quantity = item.quantity.as[Int] * 2, _.name = item.name.toLowerCase)
  }
val newRoot = root.copy(_.order.items = newItems)
```